# How to filter NULLs based on whether a column value has only one record or not, T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a dataset not too dissimilar from this:
[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9zuP.jpg)

Or seen here:

```
| RECORD_VALUE | RECORD_ATTRIBUTE |
| :--- | :--- |
| ABC | NULL |
| DEF | 123 |
| DEF | 456 |
| GHI | NULL |
| GHI | 789 |
```

From that picture, I would like to filter such that the row for record "ABC" is kept, but that the record with a "NULL" value in Col_B for record "GHI" is removed. Basically, for records that do have a value other than "NULL" in Col_B, I only want the record(s) with values. But for records that only have an associated "NULL" value in Col_B, I want to keep the entire record.

I would appreciate any ideas! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to skin this cat.

One method is to read the data first to get the ones with NOT NULL in Col_B, then join back to the table to get the relevant values.

However, this approach involves one read of the data - and then processing based on that (saves doing 2 table reads).

```
WITH A AS
    (SELECT Col_A, 
            Col_B, 
            MAX(Col_B) OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A) AS Max_ColB
      FROM yourtable
    )
SELECT A.Col_A, A.Col_B
FROM  A
WHERE (Max_ColB IS NULL) 
      OR (Max_ColB IS NOT NULL AND Col_B IS NOT NULL);
```

The above finds the maximum value of Col_B for each value in Col_A, which will be NULL if all the values of Col_B are NULL, else will be an actual value.

Then the main part sorts through those - reporting all rows when the Max_ColB is NULL, or only reporting lines where Col_B is NOT NULL is the Max_ColB has a value.

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=30cb1496b7fa62e11be9a4e80d328141) with your example data and results. It also includes the CTE component broken out (the WITH... part) showing its results.